# Magnitude of torque in this case

Tags: physics

[image]

I want to solve this problem so I need help. The problem wants to determine which is in the direction (+) or (-) and value of torque. I think an answer: In the direction (-) and 5F.r

Comment: can someone answer me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total (positive) clockwise moment about the centre of the circle is $$3F\cdot r+2F\cdot2r-F\cdot r=6Fr$$

[Relative to the centre of the circle, the $3F$ and $2F$ are acting clockwise and the $F$ is acting anti-clockwise. The diagram indicates that clockwise is positive, so the total is positive.]

Comment: According to your diagram, clock wise is positive, so it's positive

Comment: why is it clock wise?

Comment: Relative to the centre of the circle, the $3F$ and $2F$ are acting clockwise and the $F$ is acting anti-clockwise. The diagram indicates that clockwise is positive, so the total is positive.

Comment: can you add this into your answer? (Also thank you so much !)

Comment: Great! Thank you again. Have a nice day